# Quantum statistical distributions follow:$n_i=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}+c}$. Are there distributions with different $c$ other than FD/BE?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, bosons

Quantum statistical distributions play a pivotal role in describing the behavior of particles in different quantum states. The well-known Bose-Einstein, Fermi-Dirac, and Maxwell-Boltzmann distributions are characterized by their similar distribution formulae.

These different distributions in (quantum) statistical mechanics are for fermions, bosons and classical particles:

$$\text{Bose-Einstein}:\ \ \left\langle n_i\right\rangle=\frac{1}{e^{\beta\left(\epsilon_i-\mu\right)}-1}$$

$$\text{Maxwell-Boltzmann}:\ \ \left\langle n_i\right\rangle=\frac{1}{e^{\beta\left(\epsilon_i-\mu\right)}}$$

$$\text{Fermi-Dirac}:\ \ \left\langle n_i\right\rangle=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}+1}$$

where $β$ is the inverse temperature, $ϵ_i$​ is the energy of the quantum state, and $μ$ is the chemical potential.

This can be summarized as:

$$\left\langle n_i\right\rangle=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_i-\mu)}+c};\ \ \ \ \ \ c=-1,0\ \text{or} \ 1$$

Traditionally, these distributions are associated with bosons, fermions, and classical particles, respectively. My question pertains to the possibility of introducing alternative values for the parameter "$c$," such as $c=3$ or even $c=π$.

**Theoretical Considerations**: Could theoretical frameworks accommodate distributions with unconventional values of "$c$"? How might such variations impact the statistical behavior of particles?

**Real-world Correspondence**: Do these hypothetical distributions correspond to any known physical systems or phenomena? Are there examples in nature where particles exhibit behavior aligned with non-traditional values of "$c$"?

Any insights or references on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Spin statistics theorem implies that we should only have to deal with these cases. There is also a lot of literature on anyons, the 2D loophole that allows for more fun.